# Image serving and storage mechanism

Tags: image, service, cdn

My website publishes entertainment news daily. There are many number of images and videos we publish every day through admin panel. Currently the overall folder occupied 20 GB to store videos and images.

The main problem with this is, it is taking too much time for us to take backup of images and videos folder. The main concern is backing up files becoming tedious job.

Having seen some documents regarding Amazon S3, one of my friends told that we can use their services to store images and videos there instead of storing in our server.

Can you please suggest me whether to use Amazon service could be better? Is there any alternative solution like Akamai?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make backups faster, you need to look into 'incremental backups' that only back up what's changed.  There are lots of possible solutions there, and I won't presume to choose one for you.

If you want to store large bits of data elsewhere, Amazon's S3 will do that, but note that you'll be paying a monthly fee for both storage and bandwidth consumed, which may exceed your budget if you've got a high-bandwidth site.

Amazon also has a Content Delivery Network (CDN) offering (which is what Akamai basically is) to reduce bandwidth to your main site, but I don't know much about it other than that it exists.

Hope these pointers help!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking in to either a script to automatically do backups, a software solution like BackupExec, or a hardware backup such as a tape drive.

20GB really isn't that much. A simple rsync script to backup to an external hard drive wouldn't take too long, and can run in the background automatically at specific intervals. No user intervention required!